# Clare, who I work with, is organising the London marathon this year

Tags: ielts

I have read a rule of [relative clause reductions](https://www.grammarbank.com/reduced-relative-clauses.html), and it states,

*2. We can use participles when reducing the sentence.*

*a) Present Participle "V-ing" (simultaneous)*

> 1) *We stood on the bridge which connects the two halves of the city.*
>
> > ***`//the relative clause is a defining clause.`***
>
> a) *We stood on the bridge connecting the two halves of the city.*
>
> > *`//omitting by replacing them with present participle`*

Since the example has stated only about a sentence that contains a defining clause, that makes me curious whether we can also omit the **pronoun**s with or without the **to be** verb in the **non-defining relative clauses** of the sentences below,

> 2) Clare, **who works with me**, is organising  the London marathon this year.
>
> 3) Clare, **who is working with me**, is organising the London marathon this year.

into this sentence:

> b) Clare, **working with me**, is organising the London marathon this year.

If so, why?

Comment: It changes the meaning -- think again.

Comment: Congratulations on your doing the London marathon.

Comment: @TimLymington I changed it into 
"organising", ty for the remark :)

Comment: I'm not a native speaker @Kris. Could you tell me what the meaning of **"Clare, working with me, is organising the London marathon this year."** is please?

Comment: It **could** mean that "Clare, ** working along with me** is organizing ...," i.e., joining me in organizing. Which is not the meaning in the original sentence. HTH.

Comment: And since you're so kind, could you provide me some reference about it please? Sadly, I did my research but didn't find anything useful. :(

Comment: Regarding the spelling, if the sentence is a quotation then **do not change** the spelling.

Comment: Read it by rephrasing: "Working with me, Clare is organising the London marathon this year."

Comment: Also, the answer from Chasly should be of help to you. Good Luck.

Comment: Newsflash:  you would say  "Clare works with me on organizing the Marathon this year."  (note - ***of course*** it is ambiguous.  Finding English ambiguous is like noticing the ocean is slightly wet.  The "ambiguous" aspect is an utter non issue.)

Comment: Actually new user, it's totally unclear WHICH meaning you meant!  the solution is as simple as "Clare and I are working on the Marathon this year."  It's that simple.

Comment: Could it be as simple as "Clare, with whom I work, is organizing the London marathon this year"? To my eyes that completely removes any ambiguity and reads better too.

Comment: @Spratty I award you +1 internet for being the only hit on this page for the correct word to use: "whom"

Comment: @AaronF - thanks; I can always use an extra internet :-)

Comment: What about simply: "**My coworker, Clare, is organizing the London Marathon this year.**"?  That leaves zero ambiguity, and the sentence flows much more smoothly.

Comment: as an aside, if we insert a comma in the second case - "We stood on the bridge, connecting the two halves of the city" it would mess things up in a way where "We stood on the bridge, which connects the two halves of the city." doesn't

Comment: @Spratty I think it'd rather be **whom I work with** than **with whom I work**, since it sounds more familiar to me; however, both are grammatical

Comment: There is a difference between the title of the entry and the body. The title says "Doing the London Marathon" which usually means running in it, not organising it. If Claire is running in the marathon there is no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @BoldBen Ty, for the remark. It was edited.

Answer (score 13):

As Kris points out in a comment, this doesn't work.

> Clare, who works with me, is organising the London marathon this year.

Clare is organising. I don't necessarily have any connection with the event. It happens that Clare works with me.

> Clare, who is working with me, is organising the London marathon this year.

This sentence is slightly ambiguous but, as a native speaker, I would interpret it to mean, "Clare, who *currently* is working with me, is organising the London marathon this year."
Again I may not have any involvement with the marathon.

> Clare, working with me, is organising the London marathon this year.

This indicates unambiguously that Clare and I are working *together* on the organisation of the marathon.

**Explanation**

In the first two, "who is working with me"is adjectival and describes something about Clare.

In the last sentence, "working with me" is adverbial to the verb 'organising'.

Comment: I think there would be even more ambiguity if we said: _Clare, who I am working with, is organising the London marathon this year_. In that case, it's even a little harder to tell if the “work“ refers to the marathon, or some other employment.

Comment: @J.R. That’s funny – I perceive almost no ambiguity in that version. I really have to stretch my understanding to turn it into a case of ‘I’ organising the marathon together with Clare.

Comment: The last one sounds really strange to me.  (And totally ambiguous.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It could be the case that the organizing the marathon is part of a larger body of work.  For example if the speaker was the lead manager of  the construction of a building and said "Claire, who I am working with, is overseeing the elevator installation".